# What is the recommended way to update SSL certs in a Nginx cluster behind HAProxy?

Tags: ssl, nginx, lets-encrypt

So I want to have this:

```
       /  Nginx1 (SSL)
HAProxy-- Nginx2 (SSL)
       \  Nginx3 (SSL)
```

But I have questions:

1. How do I update Letsencrypt certs on all nodes?
2. If I can't do this with `certbot` (+some config) - how do you do this? Maybe some distributed k/v storages?

Comment: Are each of the Nginx instances using the same certificate, or unique ones (different private keys, different SANs, etc.)? If you can't do TLS renewal due to HAProxy, you might consider DNS validation for renewal. See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/758237) using the dehydrated ACME client.

Comment: Currently all nodes should have absolutely same certs

Comment: If HAProxy is proxying/load balancing the Nginx boxes, and they won't be connected to directly from the outside, you could just host the Lets Encrypt certificate on the HAProxy machine, and use self-signed certs for the backend machines. Or if you wanted them all to use a Lets Encrypt certificate, you could have one box - most likely the HAProxy if it's the frontend - do the certificate renewal. You'd then have a script or cron job copy the certificate and key to all the other boxes (scp, rsync over ssh, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing is to use HTTP only services (not HTTPS) on Nginx nodes and configure SSL on balancer.

Options:

1. **Traefik**. Can be configured to *auto update* LetsEncrypt certs.
2. **Fabio**. Also can be configured to use SSL certs. (I've used Hashicorp Vault to store them). Need to configure updates myself.

Those 2 integrate well with service discovery tools like Consul.